Smallest possible cardinality of finite set with two non-elementarily equivalent magmas which satisfy the same $\forall$-theory?
This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: Smallest possible cardinality of finite set with two non-elementarily equivalent magmas which satisfy the same quasi-equations?. My question now is, does there exist a finite set $S$ and two binary operations $+$ and $*$ on $S$ such that $+$ and $*$ satisfy the same $\forall$-sentences, but not the same full first-order theory? And if so, what is the smallest possible cardinality of $S$? And if not, is there at least an infinite set and two binary operations on it with this property?

I assume that $\forall$-sentence means a universal
sentence.
Think of the operation $+$ as fixed and say $S$ has $n$ elements. Then the
sentence "whenever $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ are distinct elements, then there is some
permutation of these elements that gives the same multiplication table as $(S,
+)$" is a (pretty long) $\forall$-sentence$^\dagger$. So for finite $S$, the two
operations automatically give isomorphic magmas.
However, there are examples of infinite magmas satisfying the same
$\forall$-sentences but not having the same first-order theory. An important
fact for finding an example is the one mentioned in the post I linked earler: if
$M$ is a substructure of $N$, then every universal sentence that holds in $N$
also holds in $M$. So if we can find non-elementarily equivalent magmas each of
which is isomorphic to a substructure of the other, we're done. This is a bit
reminiscent of the negation of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, and in fact I
will give an example which I know as an example demonstrating that the
Schroeder-Bernstein theorem fails in the category of (abelian) groups.
Consider the direct sums
$M = \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \dotsb$
and
$N = \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \oplus \dotsb$.
These are countable abelian groups, and clearly each is isomorphic to a subgroup
of the other. However they are distinguished by the first-order sentence "there
is an element of order $2$ which is not of the form $x + x$". Since both are
countable, you can take them to have the same underlying set.

$^\dagger$: Choose an enumeration $y_1, \dotsc, y_n$ of $S$,
and let $a(i, j)$ be the unique number such that $y_i + y_j = y_{a(i, j)}$. Then
the sentence I'm talking about is
\begin{equation*}
 \forall x_1 \dotsm \forall x_n
 \left(
  \left(
    \bigwedge_{i \ne j} x_i \ne x_j
  \right)
  \rightarrow
  \left(
   \bigvee_{\sigma \in S_n} \bigwedge_{i, j} x_{\sigma(i)} \ast x_{\sigma(j)} = x_{\sigma(a(i, j))}
  \right)
 \right)
\end{equation*}
